# How to sort list of dates in apex and return the entire record?

Tags: apex, before-trigger, wrapper-class, sort

I have a custom object called `Insurance` which has a `Start Date` field. I am planning to use bubble sort to sort the records based on the `Start Date`. This is what I have tried so far and got confused as to how to return all the records after sorting the dates.

```
 //Sorting logic 
          List<Insurance__c> listOfRecords = new List<Insurance__c>();
        integer iterationSize = listOfRecords.size();
        for(Insurance__c iList1 : insuranceList){
            listOfRecords.add(iList1);
        }
        
        
        
        for(integer y=0; y<listOfRecords.size();y++){
            boolean swapped = false;
            for(integer x =0; x< iterationSize; x++)
            {
                if(x+1 == listOfRecords.size()) break;
                if(listOfRecords.get(x).IAR_Start_Date__c < listOfRecords.get(x+1).IAR_Start_Date__c)
                {
                    Insurance__c swapVal = listOfRecords.get(x);
                    swapped = true;
                    listOfRecords.set(x, listOfRecords.get(x+1));
                    listOfRecords.set(x+1, swapVal);
                }
            }
            iterationSize--;
            if(!swapped){y= listOfRecords.size();}
            
        }
```

Edit 1: Insurance Wrapper Class to sort the records based on the IAR Start Date

```
global class InsuranceWrapper implements Comparable {
    
    public Insurance__c ins;
    public Date insuranceDate;
    
    public InsuranceWrapper(Insurance__c i){
        ins = i;
        insuranceDate = i.IAR_Start_Date__c;
    }
    
      // Compare Insurance based on the Insurance Date.
    global Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {
        // Cast argument to OpportunityWrapper
        InsuranceWrapper compareToins = (InsuranceWrapper)compareTo;

        // The return value of 0 indicates that both elements are equal.
        Integer returnValue = 0;
        if (insuranceDate > compareToins.insuranceDate) {
            // Set return value to a positive value.
            returnValue = 1;
        } else if (insuranceDate < compareToins.insuranceDate) {
            // Set return value to a negative value.
            returnValue = -1;
        }

        return returnValue;       
    }
    
    

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting a List of different object Lists by datetime](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/277812/sorting-a-list-of-different-object-lists-by-datetime) and [My bubble sort seems to be prioritizing one object over the other. and not actually sorting by createdDate](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/277979/my-bubble-sort-seems-to-be-prioritizing-one-object-over-the-other-and-not-actua)

Comment: Hi, I don’t want to use any wrapper class rather need to implement the above logic using bubble sort.

Comment: @RubenDG I have made changes to the sorting logic but still it is not sorting. Do you know hat could be the issue?

Comment: @Krishnamurthy by the way, do not use bubble sort in production code. It will time out for even moderately sized lists. Bubble sort's efficiency approaches O(0.5(n^2)) records with this version of the sorting algorithm, while the built-in list.sort method approaches O(log2) efficiency. At 300 records in the list, it would take 450,000 comparison operations, while list.sort can do it in just a couple thousand.

Comment: Also, see [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/95685/2984) I wrote that demos Comparable and even introduces a Comparator interface for plug-and-play functionality.

Comment: @sfdcfox I have added a separate wrapper class which sorts the insurance records based on date. I want to get the list of sorted records and pass it to another for loop. How do I do that?

Comment: @Krishnamurthy You use another loop to pull the records back out again.

Comment: @sfdcfox I’m not able to do that since the data type is Insurance__c whereas the wrapper has datatype of InsuranceWrapper. How do I convert the InsuranceWrapper to Insurance__c list?

Comment: `Insurance__c[] sortedRecords = new Insurance__c[0]; for(InsuranceWrapper item: items) { sortedRecords.add(item.record); }`

Comment: @sfdcfox I am getting an error saying that variable `record` does not exist.

`List<InsuranceWrapper> employees = getEmployees(insuranceList);
        employees.sort();
        Insurance__c[] sortedRecords = new Insurance__c[0]; 
        for(InsuranceWrapper item: employees) 
        { 
            sortedRecords.add(item.record);
        }`

Comment: @Krishnamurthy you called it `ins` apparently. I was just providing a generic algorithm. It's the inverse of putting the records into the wrapped list to begin with.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox . Just before your answer, I figured it out. Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is sorting the list you created in place by swapping values between pairs of indexes. So you should return `listOfRecords`.

But the early code is wrong; it leaves `iterationSize` always zero. So move that assignment to after `listOfRecords` has values added.

A [Comparable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_comparable.htm) wrapper is a reliable and common approach. While it is tedious to code it isn't complicated and you benefit from an already proven sort method. Why don't you want to use that approach?

**PP**

The wrapper approach could be e.g.:

```
public class Sorter {

    private class Wrapper implements Comparable {

        Insurance__c record;

        Wrapper(Insurance__c record) {
            this.record = record;
        }

        public Integer compareTo(Object o) {

            Insurance__c that = (Insurance__c) o;

            Date thisValue = this.record.IAR_Start_Date__c;
            Date thatValue = that.record.IAR_Start_Date__c;            

            // Assumes dates never null
            if (thisValue < thatValue) return -1;
            else if (thisValue > thatValue) return 1;
            else return 0;
        }
    }
        
    public static List<Insurance__c> sort(List<Insurance__c> records) {

        // Wrap
        List<Wrapper> wrappers = new List<Wrapper>();
        for (Insurance__c record : records) wrappers.add(new Wrapper(record));

        // Use the platform's built in sort algorithm
        wrappers.sort();

        // Unwrap
        List<Insurance__c> results = new List<Insurance__c>();
        for (Wrapper wrapper : wrappers) results.add(wrapper.record);

        return results;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Keith. I have already figured it out. I haven’t used wrapper classes. May I know what’s it? Could you share any resources where I can learn step by step?

Comment: @Krishnamurthy, Oe example here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/48000/sort-wrapper-list-by-two-values but just Google for more. For sorting, the point is to add another method - `compareTo` - via a class that holds a reference to the class being sorted.

Comment: In my case I would need to compare the dates and return the records as a whole. How to achieve the same? This is super new to me.

Comment: @Krishnamurthy See the **PS** I added.

Comment: Thanks Keith! I’ve already seen it. I was just thinking about the test class for the same but after seeing other posts, I just realised that I need to insert records with appropriate dates for the comparable class to get covered. Right?

Comment: Yes: set up some data, call your sort, then assert the results of the sort.